# center align div image variable width

Tags: html, width, alignment, center

I've found a few threads / FAQs about this, but none of what's suggested seems to work for me, so I'm not sure if there's something else going on with my code....but the example can be seen here:
http://www.503rephotography.com/_temp/

Here is the code for the div content section of the page:

```
div#content
 {
position:absolute;
top:550px;
width:90%;
padding-top:0px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
border:1px solid;
margin: 0px auto;
display:table-cell;
font-family:PaloAltoHeavy, Verdana;
font-size:1.4em;
}
```

and it's not centered on the page. I've put a border on there just to make it obvious where it sits.

My other issue is the navigation div at the top - I'm trying to get that centered, and I have the logo.png image put at a certain place, but I'm trying to make the div box 1000 pixels wide and in the center of the page with the content in there.

Lastly, I know I'm going into a lot here, I have an image with a width of 100%, and I'd like to have content under this image, but since the width varies depending on their resolution, so does the height, so putting a fixed number in for where to position the content is impossible since it will be different for various resolutions. Any input would be very much appreciated, I've been looking forever for some way to do this, and I know it's possible!

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for us so we can work on the code? :)

Answer (score 0):

since you did not post a JSFiddle, I only got this far.

Making the div be centered is because you have to put in the html `align:"center";` after the div's name.
Second, to make the div fully in the middle you can make it a `Left:auto;` and `Right:auto;`

I made the div's width 100% to make it easy in the middle like this:

```
div#content {
position: absolute;
top: 550px;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
border: 1px solid;
margin: 0px auto;
display: table-cell;
font-family: PaloAltoHeavy, Verdana;
font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

And ofcourse I did put the align center thingy in it aswell.